# TXB extension files

Tags: encryption, decode

I have an old software that uses some kind of database that saving the data on TXB/TZB files. The data in those files looks like this:

```
   1911        ¸£
    1913        ¼£
    1916        ְ£
    1921        ִ£
    1922        ָ£
    1923        ּ£
    1924        װ£
    1925        ה£
    1926        ט£
    1929        ל£
    1930        פ£
    1931        £
    1932        ₪
    1933        ₪
    1934        ,₪
    1935        <₪
    1936        h₪
    1937        x₪
    1938        €₪
    1939        ”₪
```

Someone know this extension? How to decode the data? it displays the data partially (Years in the example above), but around that data there are some unrecognized characters.

Comment: This is not a standard extension and used in many games for example.  So we can help you more if you explain what software.

Comment: @Timmetje I can tell you which software, but no one knows it. Basically it is a search engine for contacts, shopping lists, calendar and more personal stuff. The data is contacts, shopping lists, calendar and more like this.